# Why .net 8.0.100 is a preview?

Tags: .net, .net-8.0

Every search on google and microsoft.com says that .NET was "released on November 14".. I installed 8.0.100 today and when I tried to create a new project it says "preview".

When is the real release? and how do you find out if it is release or preview without installing it? I dont see any mentioning of "preview" on the download page nor in the articles

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0

[image]

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ###### *when I tried to create a new project it says "preview".*

   Install the latest Visual Studio since (as it is said in the release notes):

   > ##### Visual Studio Compatibility
   >
   > You need Visual Studio 17.8 or later to use .NET 8.0 on Windows.

   Otherwise it seems that you are running older VS version with [Preview Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/environment-preview-features-options?view=vs-2022) enabled.
2. ###### *When is the real release?*

   November 14, 2023
3. ###### *how do you find out if it is release or preview without installing it?*

   The link you have provided should be enough, but here are some extra ones if you are not convinced:

   - [.NET and .NET Core Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) (or [this one](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy))
   - [Microsoft .NET and .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-and-net-core)
   - [.NET 8 release notes @github](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/8.0/8.0.0/8.0.0.md)
4. ###### *I dont see any mentioning of "preview" on the download page nor in the articles*

   Because (as it mentioned in the support policy article) it is not supported anymore:

   > ##### Preview releases
   >
   > The support lifecycle for applicable pre-releases is as follows.
   >
   > | Version | Release Date | End of Support |
   > | --- | --- | --- |
   > | .NET 8 RC2 | October 10, 2023 | November 14, 2023 |
   > | .NET 8 RC1 | September 12, 2023 | October 10, 2023 |

   Though if you scroll down the download page you will be able to see the preview and release candidates versions:

   [image]

Comment: just to clarify - i havent had any RC installed. i went for clean install first time yesterday. downloaded 8.0.100 and thats it. Tried to upgrade VS from 17.7.7 to 17.8 and it says "VS 17.8 Preview".. decided to wait till things settle down. i dont like previews/RC on my work machine

Answer (score 2):

Install the latest version of Visual Studio (17.8), then .Net 8 will appear without preview.

Comment: This is what the existing accepted answer already says.