# The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0. Either target .NET 7.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have this issue
Error   NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 7.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0.

I have updated dotnet version and this is what dotnet --info gives[image]

when i try to create a new application its dotnet 8 is showing as preview mode[image]
some one please help fix this

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? You'll need to be on at least 17.8 - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-8/#:~:text=NET%208%2C%20the%20Visual%20Studio,way%20to%20get%20started%20with%20.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why .net 8.0.100 is a preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77573757/why-net-8-0-100-is-a-preview)